# Function arguments in python that may or may not exist

Tags: python, function, arguments

So I have an example function here:

```
def options(option1,option2):
    if option1 == 'y':
        print("Yay")
    else:
        print("No")

    if option2 == 'y':
        print("Cool")
    else:
        print("Stop")
```

Then, once I call the function, I must use all required arguments that are listed.

```
userInput = input("Type Y or N: ")
userInput2 = input("Type Y or N: ")
options(userInput,userInput2)
```

Now here's my question:

I'm making a text-based adventure game where the user can select options 1 - 4. I want to have one defined method that I will be able to call no matter how many options are offered. In one scene, I may have 3 options to give the user. In another, I may only have 1. How can I stop from having to do this:

```
#if there's 4 options in the scene call this method:
def options4(option1,option2,option3,option4):
    blabla

#if there's 3 options in the scene call this method:
def options3(option1,option2,option3):
    blabla

#if there's 2 options in the scene call this method:
def options2(option1,option2):
    blabla

#if there's 1 option in the scene call this method:
def options1(option1):
    blabla
```

Could I potentially nest the function?

Comment: Perhaps consider making the options a List so you can have a single function that handles any number of options.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function with optional parameters, e.g.:

```
def options(option1='N', option2='N'):
    print(option1, option2)
```

Now you can call it with any number of parameters, e.g.:

```
options(option2='Y')
#N Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class of this. A class can make function calls much cleaner. I would suggest doing something like:

```
`class Options:
     def __init__ ():
         self.option1 = None
         self.option2 = None
         # ect.

    def choice4 (op1,op2,op3,op4):
        # function 
   # ect`
```

otherwise, you can try a dictionary, or as others suggested, create a list